# ver un archivo PDF que no sea a través del visualizador de navegador en ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Estoy desarrollando una herramienta que genera unos archivos PDF  y se visualizan a en el navegador, pero quisiera que no fuera posible descargar el archivo, lo cual no funcionaria si lo sigo haciendo así, ya que en navegador siempre permitirá descargar, por lo tanto creo que la solución es  abrir el archivo a través de otro visualizador que no tenga la opción de descargar, pero no he encontrado otra opción que me permita hacer esto

Comment: Qué pretendes conseguir con eso? Si una persona **en realidad** quiere la información, solo basta con tomar una captura de pantalla. Si no quieres que bajen el archivo, pónlo en una carpeta de google drive y le das disable download. Aparte de esto, no hay mucho que puedas hacer.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, mi intención es visualizar el archivo y no permitir que este se edite  ya que es información importante, a demás el archivo se genera dinámicamente en el servidor  con los registros en la base de datos, ¿conoce alguna forma de subir archivos a drive generados dinámicamente?

Comment: Dos comentarios: 1 - Si estás preocupado acerca de la integridad de los datos, entonces, evitar la descarga no te va a ayudar en nada. Puedes, sin embargo, tomar otras medidas, como [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) para asegurarte que el contenido del archivo no ha sido modificado. Puedes probar varios [otros métodos](https://www.cypressdatadefense.com/blog/data-tampering-prevention/) . 2- Para subir archivos a google drive visita [este link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)